# Weed Eater Hat not awarded according to specified description

Tags: support, winter-bash-2015, tumbleweed-badge

Either the Weed Eater hat requirements description is incomplete, or there is a problem with it.  It appears to require that the tumbleweed question you answer be *someone else's* question.

I answered [my own tumbleweed](https://superuser.com/questions/1003637/installing-whs-2011-64-bit-on-windows-10-hyper-v) and accepted it, but was not awarded this hat.

Comment: I changed the tags to support instead of bug. Rollback if you feel it's wrong :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Taking a cue from [What are the requirements to get the “Weed Eater” hat?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271032/311398)

The first point is

> The answer was posted during Winter Bash and is not a self-answer.

And hence *I answered my own tumbleweed and accepted it, but was not awarded this hat* is not a bug but intended.

Comment: Thanks.  I assumed a site originally for software developers would be more precise in the specified requirements. :-(

Comment: @James I've listed some of the implicit things (including this very one) here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245122/why-didnt-or-did-i-or-some-other-user-get-a-hat-although-the-requirements-wer. Let's be honest here: You tried to cheat, and are just disappointed that we foresaw it :)

Comment: Yay! @balpha I was 1000th view on the question http://i.stack.imgur.com/uQKLJ.png \o/ :)

Comment: @balpha, I think cheat is a pretty strong word, and I certainly wouldn't describe it that way. Cheat implies that I was trying to *not* do what was required by using some else's work as my own or intentionally bypassing the rules.  I tried to get a hat in the easiest possible way following the rules that were specified, and happened to notice a possible scenario that fit within the stated rules.  Isn't that what we all do every day as developers?  If I had created new accounts or hacked into the system, *that* would be cheating.

Comment: Lol, James. @balpha was clearly joking (See the :) at the end). Also usually friends call each other as *Hey you cheater*, that doesn't imply that you are a cheater, It's just a friendly term.